# Cannot start a cluster with status "RotatingClusterCertificates (Stopped)"

Tags: azure-aks

An AKS cluster stopped working so I hit Stop with the intention of restarting. I found in deeper in the Azure blades that the certificates need to be rotated with `az aks rotate-certs`. Unfortunately I tried this while it was in a Stopped state. Now every aks command complains about not executing on a stopped cluster and the key rotation is not happening.

Things I've tried:

- `az resource update`
- `az aks start`
- `az aks operation-abort` (from the aks-preview extension)
- `az aks nodepool update`
- `az aks upgrade`

All above result in `Operations are not allowed when the managed cluster is not in the Running power state.`

Also tried scaling the VMSS for pools to 1 (from 0) manually via Portal to see if it would 'jump start' something.

Looking for a way to either cancel the rotation operation while it's powered off (so I can power it on and then do the rotation) or to force the cluster to power on so it can complete the rotation...

Comment: what is the version of AKS you are running?

Comment: 1.19.9 - Can't upgrade from a stopped state unfortunately

Comment: unfortuently I saw this error too many times. I think you can create a support ticket with Azure to see if it can be fixed. But mostly, you will need to create a new cluster :( .

The wierd thing is that the az aks start command should at least throw a different error.

Comment: Thanks, yes I have a ticket open as well but was hoping to get an answer faster via SO